# disable or block streaming, video and audio in squid proxy

Tags: proxy, mime-types, mime, squid

I'm working in a squid proxy and I need to disable or block streaming, video and audio. I read about mime types who can disable or block videos from youtube, vimeo or other type of things.

I found this:

```
acl deny_rep_mime_flashvideo rep_mime_type video/x-flv
http_reply_access deny deny_rep_mime_flashvideo
```

And when I start the Squid.. nothing happened.

Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: The [wiki](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/BlockingMimeTypes) suggests exactly that, but it's not working for `image/gif` as tested with a [gif](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif) from WIkipedia (which does return `content-type: image/gif` header)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also new to Squid things..Try this, its blocking the streaming but if the users have any youtube downloaders then vdo is getting downloaded. But the streaming is not happening.

```
acl audio_video_request req_mime_type -i ^application/x-shockwave-flash$
acl audio_video_request req_mime_type -i ^video/x-ms-asf$
acl audio_video_request req_mime_type -i ^application/vnd.ms.wms-hdr.asfv1$
acl audio_video_request req_mime_type -i ^application/x-mms-framed$
acl audio_video_request req_mime_type -i ^audio/x-pn-realaudio$
acl audio_video_reply rep_mime_type -i ^application/x-shockwave-flash$
acl audio_video_reply rep_mime_type -i ^video/x-ms-asf$
acl audio_video_reply rep_mime_type -i ^application/vnd.ms.wms-hdr.asfv1$
acl audio_video_reply rep_mime_type -i ^application/x-mms-framed$
acl audio_video_reply rep_mime_type -i ^audio/x-pn-realaudio$
```

Regards,
Vignesh K
vikkymoorthy@yahoo.com